# addition of two month and year in asp.net with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

addition of two month and year in asp.net with c#.

if i select any one **Month/year**: like march/2014 and add(+) 12 month,
so it should be give the **February/2014**.

[image]

In this we can see Loan Period is: 12 (month) and below we can see loan start from month: 07(july/2014) so end of the load should be 06/2015. and the both month are in textbox it means they are string.

Comment: march/2013 you mean!!!!!

Comment: TIL February 2014 is 12 months after March 2014... Also, how are you presenting the Month and Year inputs?

Comment: @Neel i mean users can select any one from calender in asp.net

Comment: Why 03.2013 + 12 months should give 02.2014?

Comment: March + 0 months = March. +1 month is April. +2 months is May. +6 months is September. +12 months is March again. If you count it out one by one you will definitely not get february by adding 12 months.

Comment: @x2. bcz any user select from month & year like 10/2014 for 12 month or 18 months, it's should be add with 10/2014. like user select 10/2014 this month and for 18 month it should be display 04/2016.

Answer (score 1):

Here you will not get 02/2015 if you add 12 months in 03/2014. You will get 03/2015 in result as shown below.

```
   var inputString = "march/2014";
   DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(inputString, "MMMM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
   var result = dt.AddMonths(12).ToString("MMMM/yyyy");
```

Will result in => `"march/2015"`

Comment: How it should be work... var inputString = TextBox1.Text;
        DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(inputString, "MMMM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        var result = dt.AddMonths(TextBox2.Text).ToString("MMMM/yyyy");
        Response.Write(result.ToString());                                      Textbox1 and Textbox2 are CalendarExtender.

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2013, 1, 1);

dt.AddYear(1);
dt.AddMonths(2);
//Date is 2014, 3 (March), 1

Alternatively if you wish to substrat years and months you can use:

dt.AddYear(-1);
dt.AddMonths(-1);
//Date is 2013, 2 (February),1
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that yous should add *-1*, not *12* months (if you want to get *February* from *March*):

```
 String fromDate = "march/2013";

 // result == "February/2013"
 String result = DateTime
   .ParseExact(fromDate, "MMMM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
   .AddMonths(-1)
   .ToString("MMMM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

In case that you want to add a *year* and *two months* (and so your example is incorrect)

```
 String fromDate = "march/2013";

 // result == "May/2014"
 String result = DateTime
   .ParseExact(fromDate, "MMMM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
   .AddYears(1)
   .AddMonths(2)
   .ToString("MMMM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: it's helpful for me thanks.